# Whitelist sender SMTP Server in Postfix header_checks

Tags: linux, rhel, postfix, smtp

I'm trying to whitelist a SMTP server in my postfix header_checks configuration file.
To prevent Phishing mails we reject all external mails to our internal network with our company domain as e-mail address.
As we have a webshop which sends order verifications with our company domain as e-mail address we need to whitelist those e-mails.
It happens that the sender e-mail addresses change or that there are newly added addresses. Therefore we don't want to whitelist every single e-mail address separately.
It'd be much easier to whitelist the webserver sadly it's not working and the e-mails are still being dropped by postfix.
The webserver sends e-mails with phpmail().

Server specifications:
OS: RHEL7
Postfix version: 2.10.1

header_checks:

```
if /^From:.*\<.*@.*COMPANY.*\..*\>.*/
/^From:.*WHITELIST_DOMAIN_NAME\.net/                                  DUNNO
/^Received:.*WHITELIST_DOMAIN_NAME\.net/                              DUNNO
/.*WHITELIST_DOMAIN_NAME.*/                                           WARN Worked
/^From:.*@COMPANY.com.*/                                   DISCARD      FAKE ADDRESS
/^From:.*\<.*@.*COMPANY.*\..*\>.*/                         DISCARD      FAKE ADDRESS AGGRESSIVE
endif
```

Mail Header (as seen as received mail)

```
[...]
Received: from WHITELIST_SERVER.WHITELIST_DOMAIN_NAME (WHITELIST_SERVER.WHITELIST_DOMAIN_NAME [WHITELIST_IP_ADDRESS])
(using TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)
[...]
```

Postfix Logs

```
Dec 17 16:32:16 MAILSERVER postfix/cleanup[Nr.]: Mail-ID: discard: header From: DISPLAY NAME <MAILADDRESS@COMPANY> from WHITELIST_SERVER.WHITELIST_DOMAIN_NAME[WHITELIST_IP_ADDRESS]; from=<WHITELIST_SERVER.WHITELIST_DOMAIN_NAME> to=<TESTUSER@COMPANY> proto=ESMTP helo=<WHITELIST_SERVER.WHITELIST_DOMAIN_NAME>: FAKE ADDRESS
```

Thanks in advance for your help =)

Comment: Can you do it as a Spam score instead of whitelist?  This way, you can avoid applying the blacklist filter until all the filters have been applied.

Comment: Hi Alex
Thank you for your answer.
What do you mean with "spam score"? An additional file in the postfix folder for whitelisting filters only?

Comment: No, what I mean is, instead of using Black List and White List, assign spam scores to each message.  Normal spam filters work as, e.g. if the headers are forged, spam score +3.  If the message contains a word like "Viagra", spam score +1.  etc.  Anything with a score +9 or more gets blocked.  You can have the spam rules, if it's on a black list, spam score +9.  If it's on a white list, spam score -12.  Or something along those lines.